# How can I seek, go to a certain second with Youtube iOS API?

Tags: ios, html, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I have played round with `YouTube-Player-iOS-Helper` here: https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper

But I can not figure out how to start video embedded into iOS App from a certain second, any idea?

As you can see I tried

1. to add a HTML5 key-value pair `"start": 100`, but it crashes
2. and tried to seek after video loaded, `pv.seekToSeconds(100, allowSeekAhead: true)` but also has no effect

===

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var pv: YTPlayerView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        pv.loadWithVideoId("M7lc1UVf-VE", playerVars: ["controls": 0, "playsinline": 1, "autohide": 1, "showinfo": 0, "modestbranding": 1]) //, "start": 100
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "receivedPlaybackStartedNotification:", name: "Playback started", object: nil)
    }

    func receivedPlaybackStartedNotification(notification: NSNotification) {

        pv.seekToSeconds(100, allowSeekAhead: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to play a video at all ?

Comment: yes, I am able to play

Comment: Hmm.. try doing the operation in viewdidappear instead of viewdidload

Comment: Is there a check to make sure the video is at least 100 seconds long? may be a reason why it crashes when you add HTML5 key pair. I might be wrong

Comment: video is longer then 100s, I am only experimenting with one demo video

Answer (score 3):

You need to wait for the `playerViewDidBecomeReady` delegate to be called.

In Swift, that's:

```
class MyViewVc: UIViewController, YTPlayerViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var ytPlayer: YTPlayerView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.ytPlayer.delegate = self

        self.ytPlayer.load(withVideoId: "M7lc1UVf-VE")        
    }

    func playerViewDidBecomeReady(_ playerView: YTPlayerView) {
        self.ytPlayer.seek(toSeconds: 100, allowSeekAhead: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi i investigate [Github](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper/blob/master/Project/youtube-player-ios-example/youtube-player-ios-exampleTests/youtube_player_ios_exampleTests.m) example of this library. And test as well try to use this code snippet.

```
- (void)testSeekTo {
  [[mockWebView expect] stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"player.seekTo(5.5, false);"];
  [playerView seekToSeconds:5.5 allowSeekAhead:NO];
  [mockWebView verify];
}
```